# I get "has stopped working" error when I use 'Application.Exit();' in C#

Tags: c#

In my application I launch several processes, and when I use the command `Aplication.Exit();` Windows gives me the "has stopped working" error. I don't understand why, also the `Enviroment.Exit(0);` give me this error.

I use the Awesomium webcontrol, and before launch Application.Exit(); I call

```
WebCore.Shutdown();
```

and then

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/c " + @"rmdir /s/q " + dir); // erase all temporary files

Application.Exit();
```

Comment: I'd probably blame some unifinished process running in the background, like dealing with unmanaged resources which you haven't disposed  correctly.

Comment: Can you provide some of the code, a stack trace, a print screen of the debugger... not much to go on right now..

Comment: do you know the exact line where an exception occurs?  You mentioned you tried two ways of exiting but is it the line that exits that also throws the exception?

Comment: Have you stepped through with the debugger to verify it does not crash before that line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it will wait for the process to end before exiting the application:

```
// erase all temporary files    
Process process = Process.Start(@"rmdir /s/q " + dir); 
process.WaitForExit();

Application.Exit();
```

If this does not work, put a breakpoint on the process.WaitForExit() line and try to get a StackTrace / exception message to help us figure out what is going wrong.