# C# program has stopped working, Awesomium

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, awesomium

I'm using the [Awesomium](http://awesomium.codeplex.com/) plugin in [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) (.NET 4.0) and am getting "Program has stopped working" error message when closing the problem. I believe it is due to the Awesomium process that is being killed.

I've used advice from Stack Overflow quesdtion *[I get “has stopped working” error when I use 'Application.Exit();' in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16224027/c-sharp-get-has-stopped-working-error-when-i-use-application-exit/22103463?noredirect=1#comment33533562_22103463)*:

```
WebCore.Shutdown();

// Erase all temporary files
Process process = Process.Start(@"rmdir /s/q " + "Cache");
process.WaitForExit();
Application.Exit();
```

I get AccessViolationException. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem is the `process.WaitForExit();` line or passing a relative file path instead of an absolute file path.

```cs
WebCore.Shutdown();
DeleteCache();
Application.Exit();

// ...

private void DeleteCache()
{
  ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
  // get the full path to the Awesomium cache directory
  string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Cache");
  string command = String.Format("RMDIR /S /Q \""{0}\"", path);

  // get the path to cmd.exe
  info.FileName = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMSPEC") ?? "cmd.exe";

  // append the cmd.exe flags to disable auto-run scripts (/D) and to exit at completion (/C)
  info.Arguments = String.Concat("/D /C ", command);
  info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

  // start the process without waiting for completion
  Process.Start(info);
}
```

I also don't understand why Awesomium runs their own clone of SO with Awesomium Answers.  Awesomium could just simply monitor questions tagged as [awesomium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awesomium).  The Anwsers forum is even more frustrating given the irregular involvement of the Awesomium LLC developers.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem with the Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF).  I solved it by calling:

process.Kill ();

in the FormClosing () handler.